# How to find out why daemon tools supervise is exiting

Tags: node.js, unix, devops, daemontools

I run a node process (websocket server) on an AWS instance. I used to start it like this:

```
node websocket/index.js
```

But have recently swiched to using [daemontools supervise](https://cr.yp.to/daemontools/supervise.html) to run this process so that it respawns if it should quit or die for any reason.

So, I now run the process like this (from within the dir): `supervise . &`. The following is my `./run` file:

```
#!/bin/sh

node websocket/index.js
```

This generally works well. When I manually `kill -9` the Node process to test out it out, Supervise respawns it correctly.

**However, every morning when I check in on things, the Node process and the Supervise process are both dead and nowhere to be found in `ps`. I confirmed that the system is not rebooting by looking at `uptime`.**

**How can I find out why the Supervise and Node processes are dying overnight? And how can I prevent this?**

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I switched to using the node module `forever` to keep my process running, and it has been great so far.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever